# $() is removed from string

Tags: regex, replace, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to replace old validation with the new validation. But the new validation regex is removing **$()** from Regex.

```
$oldValidation="<RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern>"
$newValidation= "<RegexPattern>^[\w\s,.;+&'""!?$()@%]*$</RegexPattern>"
$_.Fields["Parameters"].value -replace $oldValidation, $newValidation
```

But the newValidation is removing `$()` from regex and showing it like this

```
<RegexPattern>^[\w\s,.;+&'"!?@%]*$</RegexPattern>
```

Comment: Check if those are special characters to the shell even in quotes (they are in bash), and learn how to escape them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help:

```
$oldValidation="<RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern>"
$newValidation= "<RegexPattern>^[\w\s,.;+&'""!?`$()@%]*$</RegexPattern>"
$_.Fields["Parameters"].value -replace [regex]::escape($oldValidation), $newValidation.Replace('$','$$')
```

Please check there is a backtick before `$`.

Another possible solution is using `.Replace` after backtick is used in `$newValidation`:

```
$_.Fields["Parameters"].value.Replace($oldValidation, $newValidation)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://regex101.com, `$` means end of line in regex.  `()` is used for capture groups.  You would have to backslash them to use them literally.